# Tangent lines to circle $ x^2+y^2=100 $ passing point (14, 2)

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

I'm asked to give  tangent lines to $ x^2+y^2=100 $, so that both tangent lines go through the point $ (14,2)$.

Implicit differentiation gives:

$dy/dx=-x/y$

While graphing I noted that the circle , doesn't go through (14,2).

I constructed the following tangent line to the point (14,2):

$ y-2=-7(x-14) $

but it's not tangent to the circle.

I'm a bit stuck, need some help :D

Comment: The circle won't go through $(14,2)$, but that's not the assignment.  The assignment is for the tangent line to go through $(14,2)$.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1778828/265466 and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the tangent lines be $x+ay-2a-14=0$. Use the distance formula between the lines and the origin,

$$\frac{|1(0)+a(0)-2a-14|}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}=10$$

which yields $a=-\frac34,\>\frac43$. Thus, the tangent lines are

$$4x-3y-50=0,\>\>\>\>\>3x+4y-50=0$$

Comment: Great answer.  I understood everything, except for how did you got to the tangent lines equation in the form of: $ x+ay-2a-14=0 $   Could you please elaborate a bit more on  how to get there?

Comment: @GerardoHernández - I just parametrized the line to make sure it contains (14, 2). There are other forms you could consider.

Comment: Alternatively, for example, you could use $ax + y -14a -2=0 $ instead.

Answer (score 2):

We form the system $$\begin{cases}y-2=m(x-14),\\x^2+y^2=100\end{cases}$$

or, by elimination

$$x^2+(m(x-14)+2)^2=100.$$

This equation has a double root (hence the line is tangent) when the delta cancels, i.e. when

$$12m^2-7m-12=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Similar question I have seen on other forum. Link given
https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/forum/topic/tanget-to-circle/?part=1#postid-38

In your question a=10 and satisfy point (14,2) on tangent you get quadratic in m find m.

Comment: Answers that are links are not stable or permanent.

Comment: I didn't get you . Re posting the link just check. https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/forum/topic/tanget-to-circle/?part=1#postid-38

Comment: It is general policy here that answers should be self-contained.  When the link breaks next month the answer becomes meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

Following your idea, the line slope is:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x_0}{y_0}$$

where $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point of the circle. So, you can't use $(x_0,y_0)=(14,2)$ because it is not a point of the circle.

Considering that, the best idea is to use @Yves's approach.